# Bootstrap layout scrollable divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bergen/ay608ucf/51/) to show what i tried, i would like to have a page without scroll bars and have the col left and col right divs get a scrollbar when they overflow.

could someone please tell me what im missing? Or if you know a cleaner solution using bootstrap please let me know.

ill paste the html here too for future reference whebn the fiddle expires.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>

  <body>


<div class="container-fluid" id="my-container">
  <div class="row" id="my-full-row">


  <div class="" id="my-menu-col">
    M
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="row" id="my-title-row">
      Title row
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="my-row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="my-col-left">
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10" id="my-col-right">
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.row {

    margin: 0px;
}
.col {

    padding: 0px;
}

#my-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#my-full-row {
    height: 100%;
}

#my-menu-col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px; 
  background-color: purple;
}

#my-title-row {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

#my-row {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

#my-col-left {
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#my-col-right {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


#u { background-color: #337ab7; }
```

Comment: I tried the answers given but it seems like the dont give the desired effect. what i am trying to achieve is that the green and yellow divs get a vertical scrollbar when the text inside is too long (instead of extending the page). There should never be a scroll bar which scrolls the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of repeated CSS, so I'd recommend cleaning that up a bit. If I understand what you are wanting, removing `height: 100%;` from `#my-row` keeps it from scrolling when the viewport is high enough for the content.

I added this too:

```
#my-col-left, #my-col-right {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: auto;` will show the bar only on overflow.

and you need to limit the height of your `div`.. so these 2 rules were changed:

```
#my-col-left {
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#my-col-right {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

here is the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/o0czt2ua/

Answer (score 0):

i have added height:100vh to these two ids #my-col-left #my-col-right and overflow:hidden to body. copy the css to your file it will work.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden; /*added*/
}
.row {

    margin: 0px;
}
.col {

    padding: 0px;
}

#my-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#my-full-row {
    height: 100%;
}

#my-menu-col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px; 
  background-color: purple;
}

#my-title-row {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

#my-row {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

#my-col-left {
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100vh;/*added*/
}

#my-col-right {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100vh;/*added*/
}


#u { background-color: #337ab7; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="my-container">
  <div class="row" id="my-full-row">


  <div class="" id="my-menu-col">
    M
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="row" id="my-title-row">
      Title row
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="my-row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="my-col-left">
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>
        col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>col left<br/>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10" id="my-col-right">
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
        col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>col right<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```